Get current source column number in LuaTeX
How can I get the current .tex source column number for tex.print command?
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
str = ""
function printtexfile (instr)
    str = str .. instr .. [[ lineno = ]] .. tex.inputlineno .. [[ columnno = ]] .. [[??]] .. [[\\]]
    tex.print(instr)
end
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}

\directlua{printtexfile("demostr-1")} \directlua{printtexfile("demostr-2")}

\directlua{printtexfile("demostr-3")}

\directlua{printtexfile("demostr-4")} \directlua{printtexfile("demostr-5")} \directlua{printtexfile("demostr-6")}

\directlua{printtexfile("demostr-7")}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
\noindent\directlua{tex.print(str)}
\end{document}



Is there a way to identify printtexfile function calls in some way? This is needed to solve this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/728613/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-insert-fragments @David Carlisle

@DavidCarlisle You misunderstood the question

@Youra_P To the best of my knowledge this is not exposed to the Lua interface, but TeX does store the column number internally. If you really want to you can recompile the engine to expose a new primitive, but I doubt that (see
e.g. https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex/issues/89 for how to compute the column number)

@user202729 ah I just re-read the question, yes my first comment made no sense:-)
